Vending machine motor working
I am trying to fix a vending machine motor and trying to run it directly without a microcontroller to understand its working, but I am not able to get it working.
The motor has 6 terminals:
T1 and T2 is for power supply (+)
T3 and T4 is negitive (-)
T5 is not in use
T6 i believe for feedback.
When I connect power supply to T1 and T3 it didn’t working and even if I press the limit switch it still don't work,
How I can start it without microcontroller?
Here's a view of the foil side of the PCB.

The component side.

The assembly.


Try 3/4 positive and 1/2 negative. One of those diodes (D2) will block power the other way round.

@Finbarr yes then it work when i connect it in that way and press limit switch.
but in actual scenario we cannot press the limit switch manually and the use of limit switch is to  monitor the one revolution .
how it will be working in production environment ?

I have no idea what you're trying to do here.

You apply continuous voltage to pins 3-4 and 1-2 as @Finbarr describes. Then to start one cycle, you momentarily ground pin 6 (i.e.,  short it to pins 1-2). And yes, if you also have a high-resistance pull-down on pin 6, you can monitor its voltage to determine when the cycle is complete.
